# Seam on Linux Problems

Tags: linux, seam

When a seam application on JBOSS using java 1,5 is deployed in Unix platform, I am getting this error.

`errorjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:141)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvi
ronment.java:62)`

It runs fine on windows platform. On my local linux machine it runs fine. but on another linux machine it works some times and sometimes it throws up the above error

Comment: @Anand I think it has nothing to do with Seam. Have you seen **at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment**

Comment: @Arthur yes looked into it, it is quite mysterious as to why the application is behaving like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check at your jboss logs which java version and java vendor are jboss using. Use only SUN Java 5 or IBM Java 5.